# Scrolling the listview multiples my view check's

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, checkedtextview

I'm pretty beginner,so take me easy. I have two listview parallel , here only listViewSelectFile he can makes check's. The problem is when i checked a item from this listview !!! Example : If i select first item from listview , next item's until i move the scroll from listview are unchecked. If on one page they can be maxim 9 item's to see (first item is check next 8 is unchecked) and the 10 item is checked then next 8 item's are unchecked then the item 19 is checked and so far one. I tested and with the phone horizontal and it's the same problem.I think the problem appear is when i move the scroll next item's(CheckTextView ID ) he give the id 0 , and he multiply my CheckTextView ID . How can i solve this ? Any example ? Thank you !!!!! If you don't get this problem maybe you can give me a example how to make 2 listview paralels with textviewcheck.

```
    PopulateListView();
```

The whole code from bot it's in PopulateListView():

```
adapterImageFileName = new ItemsAdapter(
                        screen3_select_from_lists.this, mImageFilenames);

                        listViewSelectFile.setAdapter(adapterImageFileName);

            listViewSelectFile
                    .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                            try {
                                LinearLayout item=(LinearLayout) view;
                                CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            toggle(tv);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Toggle function :

```
public void toggle(CheckedTextView v) {
    if (v.isChecked()) {
        v.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        v.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter :

```
private class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        String[] items;

        public ItemsAdapter(Context context, String[] mImageFilenames) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.items = mImageFilenames;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_view_rows, null);
            }
            CheckedTextView post = (CheckedTextView)v
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            post.setText(items[position]);
            return v;
        }

    }
```

**and my xml, 2 parallel listview's :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewSelectStudents"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            >
        </ListView>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewSelectFiles"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
        </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

list_view_rows.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <CheckedTextView  
      android:id="@+id/textView1" 
      android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
      android:paddingRight="20dip" 
      android:paddingTop="10dip"
      android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"  
      android:gravity="center_vertical"  
      android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
      android:onClick="toggle" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your view is being reused by Android in order to optimize resources. I managed to resolve this problem creating my own adapter, and saving inside my adapter the IDs I have checked. Every time my `getView` method gets called I clear the check objet and then I see if in my checked-row structure this row / ID has been checked by the user.

Then if I rotate the screen I ask to the adapter of an array of checked items  in my `onSaveInstanceState` which I reuse in my `onRestoreInstanceState` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: still don't work ,check the code from top , it's updated . You can correct my code? Thank you !

Comment: You are not uodating your listview indexes as I can see. Apart from that what youhave to do in your 'getview' method a setchecke (true or false) depending on the array you provided to the adapter